# Telegram Bot API: Send local/new photo into chat (Python 3.9)

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

I am struggling so hard on the following problem:

As the title says I want to send a picture via the Telegram Bot API. This is the code everyone is suggesting:

```
params = {'chat_id': chatId, 'caption':"This is a caption"}
img = {'photo': open(imgpath, 'rb')}    

status = requests.post(sendPhotoURL, data=params, files=img)
```

Unfortunately, that does not work for me.
I've found out that in `requests.post` `data` should be `params` in order to create/post the URL correctly. But I haven't found a solution for sending the picture via the URL.

This is the code that is working for me (so far):

```
params = {'chat_id': chatId, 'caption':"This is a caption"}
img = {'photo': open(imgpath, 'rb')}    

status = requests.post(sendPhotoURL, params=params, files=img)
print (status.url, "responsed:\n", status.status_code, ":", status.text)
```

I know the picture should be sent as a *multipart/form-data* (see: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto), which should be done by setting the parameter `files` to  `img` (which is a dictionary). By doing it this way, i still get `400 : {"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: there is no photo in the request"}`, so apparantly the API wants me to put the image into the URL.

It's very possible that I'm misunderstanding the docs or that I'm doing something incredible stupid. It would be so nice if any geeks could help me out :D!

Thanks a lot!

PS: I'm sorry for any typos or grammar/spelling mistakes. English is not my first language :D